# I fixed my PPA errors but when I try to install Steam all additional packages say No Installation Candidate

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, steam, deb

While I was downloading Steam I get this code:

```
user@computer:~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg -i steam_latest.debSelecting previously unselected package steam-launcher.
(Reading database ... 195561 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack steam_latest.deb ...
Unpacking steam-launcher (1.0.0.48) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of steam-launcher:
 steam-launcher depends on curl; however:
  Package curl is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package steam-launcher (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+14.04.20140409-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.13-1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 steam-launcher
```

However Steam is still 'installed.' When I click on it these are the results.

```
Steam needs to install these additional packages: '
    curl, libgl1-mesa-dri:i386, libgl1-mesa-glx:i386, libc6:i386
[sudo] password for tristan: 
...............................................
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package curl is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Package libc6:i386 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  libc-bin initscripts locales tzdata libdb1-compat:i386 libdb1-compat

Package libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Package libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  libgl1-mesa-glx

E: Package 'curl' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'libgl1-mesa-dri:i386' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'libgl1-mesa-glx:i386' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'libc6:i386' has no installation candidate
Press return to continue:
```

If press enter or exit out it will open again after displaying the following error message:
    You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run:
    libc.so.6

When I try to open the deb and install it through the Software Center it reads: dependency is not satisfiable curl

While I was typing this USC has deleted steam from my applications, removed steam from its Download list, readded it and when I installed it through the marketplace again I get this "Processing your request for 'Steam'..." "Information recieved." which is what it did earlier and it will go on indefinitely.

Answer (score 1):

Which Ubuntu are you running? And why do you have to install it like that? Can't you just install with this?

> sudo apt-get install steam

See
[Installing Steam on Ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/538753/installing-steam-on-ubuntu-12-04/538784#538784)

On a sidenote, you may have to install the restricted repo in USC to be able to install Steam through it.