# Installing Steam on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, package-management, steam

I'm having issues with Steam. When I attempt to get it from the USC, it tells me it needs curl. Trying to get curl (using apt-get on the terminal) doesn't work either, instead telling me:

> Package curl is not available, but is referred to by another package.
>   This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
>   is only available from another source
>
> E: Package 'curl' has no installation candidate

Is there any way to fix this? How do I get curl (and as such, Steam) to work? (And if it helps: on my 10.04 upgraded laptop, it worked fine aside from some graphical glitches)

Using the .deb just brings me to the USC.. for some reason.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific on the error the USC is giving when you try to install Steam? From my knowledge it is capable of installing dependencies if it needs to. A screen shot or a copy paste of the error would be great.

Comment: Try running `sudo apt-get update` see if you are connecting to the repositories.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/1784/how-can-i-install-steam

Comment: Ani, can you please provide screenshots of the errors? I just installed Steam on Kubuntu, Lubuntu and Ubuntu (12.04 and 14.04) right out of the box, no need for dependencies. Have you altered your packages? Here is how I did it: http://wp.me/p57m7c-26

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to just install it like this?

```
sudo apt-get install steam
```

For some reason installing steam through USC requires you to log in with Ubuntu One, but at least in 14.04 you can just install it like that.